# wro4j -- How do you disable aggregation feature in debug mode?

Tags: debugging, wro4j

I'm using wildcards to load my javascript and css files and it works great, but it's a pain to work with the aggregated javascript files during the development phase.  Is there a way to have wro4j not aggregate the files, but just include them individually?

***My `wro.xml` File***

```
<groups xmlns="http://www.isdc.ro/wro">
 <group name="external">
    <js>/app/lib/*.js</js>
 </group>

 <group name="application">
    <js>/js/*.js</js>
    <css>/css/normalize.css</css>
    <css>/css/*.css</css>
 </group>
</groups>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a trick to achieve that in development mode (`debug=true`). There is an endpoint (`/wro/wroAPI/model` - this is valid if you are mapping WroFilter to `/wro/*`) which returns a JSON representation of the model. 
Using this JSON, you can easily insert scripts and/or css links for a given group by iterating group entries. There is no such widget yet available by default, but if you create one and want to contribute it - you're welcome :).

Answer (score 3):

Thanks for the input, Alex.

I've created a ServletFilter that uses the info you provided above.  I post it here for posterity.  Note:  this isn't ideal code (caches too much, for example), it's just here to give folks an idea of what an implementation would look like.  My implementation uses Spring's `DelegatingFilterProxy` to tell the code what groups to worry about.  As far as it goes with creating a plugin, could you point me the way to some documentation for implementing, I'm hazy on that part?

```
public class WroDebugFilter implements Filter
{
    //http loader is shamelessly stolen from another project.
    SimpleHttpLoader httpLoader = new SimpleHttpLoader();

    private List<String> jscriptFiles;
    private List<String> debugGroups;

    @Override
    public void init(FilterConfig filterConfig) throws ServletException {
        //To change body of implemented methods use File | Settings | File Templates.
    }

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {

        request.setAttribute("jscriptFiles",getJavaScriptFiles((HttpServletRequest) request));

        chain.doFilter(request,response);
    }

    private List<String> getJavaScriptFiles(HttpServletRequest request) {

        if (jscriptFiles == null) {

            List<String> cssFiles = new ArrayList<String>();
            List<String> jsFiles = new ArrayList<String>();

            JsonParser jsonParser = new JsonParser();

            String url = httpLoader.httpGet(getApiUrl(request));

            JsonObject data = jsonParser.parse(url).getAsJsonObject();
            JsonArray groups = data.getAsJsonArray("groups");

            for (JsonElement group : groups) {

                JsonObject groupObject = group.getAsJsonObject();

                String groupName = groupObject.get("name").getAsString();

                if (debugGroups.contains(groupName)) {

                    JsonArray resources = groupObject.getAsJsonArray("resources");

                    for (JsonElement resource : resources) {
                        JsonObject resourceObject = resource.getAsJsonObject();
                        String uri = resourceObject.get("uri").getAsString();

                        if (uri.contains(".css")) {
                            cssFiles.add("\t<link rel=\"stylesheet\" href=\"" + request.getContextPath() + uri +"\">");
                        }
                        else {
                            jsFiles.add("<script type=\"text/javascript\" src=\"" + request.getContextPath() + uri + "\"></script>");
                        }
                    }
                }

            }
            cssFiles.addAll(jsFiles);
            jscriptFiles = cssFiles;
        }

        return jscriptFiles;
    }

    private String getApiUrl(HttpServletRequest request) {

        String serverName = request.getServerName();
        String contextPath = request.getContextPath();
        int port = request.getServerPort();

        return String.format("http://%s:%s%s/%s",serverName,port,contextPath,"wro/wroAPI/model");
    }

    @Override
    public void destroy() {
        //To change body of implemented methods use File | Settings | File Templates.
    }

    public List<String> getDebugGroups() {
        return debugGroups;
    }

    public void setDebugGroups(List<String> debugGroups) {
        this.debugGroups = debugGroups;
    }
}
```

**The `wro.xml` file**

```
<groups xmlns="http://www.isdc.ro/wro">
    <group name="external">
        <js>/app/lib/*.js</js>
    </group>

    <group name="application">
        <js>/js/*.js</js>
        <css>/css/normalize.css</css>
        <css>/css/*.css</css>
    </group>
</groups>
```

and....

**The Spring Configuration**

```
    <bean id="wroDebugFilter" class="gov.mystate.dhw.idalink.web.filter.WroDebugFilter">
        <property name="debugGroups">
                <list>
                    <value>application</value>
                </list>
            </property>
    </bean>
```